# How do options behave in Perl's Getopt::Long?

Tags: perl

I have following piece of code that I am trying to understand:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my $isheader ;

if( !GetOptions(

    "is-header!"               => \$isheader,

  ) ) { exit 1; }

print "isheader is = $isheader\n" ;
```

When I run the code as:

```
script.pl  --is-header
```

The output is:

```
isheader is = 1
```

I have put a "!" at the end of option name is-header to negate so shouldn't output be:

```
isheader is = 0
```

Secondly, if I run the script as:

```
script.pl --is
```

It is still able to print

```
isheader is = 1
```

So I guess Perl expands partial names of the options?

Thirdly, I run

```
script.pl --is-header --is-head
```

Why does it not fail with ambiguous option error? It prints

```
isheader is = 1
```

Also if I replace  is-header! with is-header+  in the above code it still prints

```
isheader is = 1
```

while I guess it should print  isheader is = 2 , why so ?

I read `https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html` and was experimenting with that to understand it, but seems like I am messing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getopt::Long supports various argument types. `foo!` declares a `--foo` option with boolean value, whereas `foo=s` would expect a string value. The `!` is not negation in this case. If you want a value that is incremented each time the option is specified use the `+` type like `foo+`. For more details, read the [Summary of Option Specifications](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Summary-of-Option-Specifications).

By default, Getopt::Long will allow abbreviated parameter names as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous. So if you have `--house` and `--home`, then both `--hou` and `--hom` would be recognized but not `--ho`. You can explicitly enable or disable this behaviour with the `auto_abbrev` configuration flag. See [Configuring Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Configuring-Getopt::Long) for all the configuration options. You can set them with the `Getopt::Long::Configure()` function.

Getopt::Long is a very complicated module with tons of configuration options. Whatever you want it to do you can probably configure it do that, but I personally prefer avoiding that complexity and the cumbersome interface. Parsing arguments by hand is not much more difficult in simple cases (e.g. options without arguments).

Comment: Re "*I personally prefer avoiding that complexity and the cumbersome interface*", [wut](https://pastebin.com/Q6f2bsqU)

Comment: @ikegami The interaction between various configuration options can get rather nontrivial, and the default config might not be intuitive – I certainly was surprised to learn about the insanity of `auto_abbrev` and `pass_through`. My viewpoint is probably tainted from having attempted to write a drop-in replacement for a subset of Getopt::Long features. But yeah, I guess Getopt::Long is perfectly fine for a large range of use cases. Thank you for suggesting `posix_default` as a sane configuration starting point.

Comment: `pass_through` is off by default, and is useful in certain circumstances. For when certain options are global and certain options are for a specific command, you can extract the global options using an initial scan with `pass_through`.

Comment: It disables `auto_abbrev`, `permute`, and `+` as a prefix. One might be tempted to say "who cares if the user wants to abbreviate", but leaving `auto_abbrev` on creates backwards compatibility issues. (e.g. If `--ignore` exists, someone might use `--i`, which prevents you later creating `--ignite`).

Comment: I included `bundling` in the above because it prevents `-long`.

Answer (score 4):

> I have put a "!" at the end of option name is-header to negate

Actually, if you read [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#A-little-bit-less-simple-options), it says this:

> A negatable option is specified with an exclamation mark ! after the option name

"Negatable" is not the same as "negated".

Negatable means that you can turn the option off by including "no" before the option's name.

```
script.pl --is_header
```

And

```
script.pl --nois_header
```